# How to create list of Google slide deck page nums that meet criteria like contains or doesn't not contain certain words or meets pages specs?

Tags: find, google-slides

Is there a way to create (and export) a list of Google slide page numbers that:

1. contain certain words
2. does not contain certain words like Copyright
3. meet certain page specification criteria like left margins less than 1" wide

I have a list of criteria that each slide in a deck must conform to in terms of content and page specifications (e.g. margin width) and it would be efficient to be able to be able to have these pages identified rather than searching each page for all the criteria.

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate your goal on your question by updating it with `sample slides` containing dummy data and your **✨expected result✨**